# Excel popup for cell calculation

Tags: vba, excel, popup

First time poster here. I am a beginner when it comes to Excel VBA code. How do I create a PopUp window that shows up when I click a cell which then updates depending on what is entered in the PopUp Window? The cell contains a number I want to be updated.

Say I have a list of cells containing numbers, I click on one of the cells and in the window popup, I write +5. The original number now updates with 5 added to it. The same would go in reverse if i wrote -5 in the PopUp window.

Comment: I have everything completed. I am trying to optimize and dummy proof the spreadsheet so multiple people can use it efficiently. The only thing preventing me from continuing further is my lack of VBA knowledge.

Comment: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim activeRange As Range
    Dim origVal As Integer
    Dim addVal  As Integer
    Dim dialogResult As String


    Set targetRange = Target(1, 1)
    Set activeRange = Range("B2:B207")

    If Not Intersect(targetRange, activeRange) Is Nothing Then

        origVal = targetRange.Value

        dialogResult = InputBox("Enter number to add")

        If dialogResult <> "" Then

            If IsNumeric(dialogResult) Then
                addVal = dialogResult
                targetRange.Value = origVal + addVal
            Else
                MsgBox "Please enter a valid number!", vbCritical
            End If

        End If


    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! Now, how do I apply this to a certain range instead of the whole spreadsheet? For example: B2:B207.